# using Boost `ptree.find` doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, boost

I have

```
const boost::property_tree::ptree& v
```

and I want to get `<xmlattr>.Value`, if it exists, otherwise the value.

I tried this code:

```
if(v.find("<xmlattr>.Value") != v.not_found())
    value = v.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.Value");
else
    value = v.get_value<std::string>();
```

However, it doesn't work as expected. Even if the value is there, `find()` returns `not_found()`.

This code works:

```
auto inValue = v.get_optional<std::string>("<xmlattr>.Value");
if(inValue.is_initialized())
    value = inValue.get();
else
    value = v.get_value<std::string>();
```

I guess I understood `find()` wrong. What exactly does it do? Is there another function I should use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, find() [(see here)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#idp97927384-bb) finds a child with the given key (not path), or not_found() if there is none.

`<xmlattr>.Value` is a path (that works with `get` and `get_optional`).

Comment: (Sorry for reopening this discussion...) I faced this same issue with **find()** and if I understand well, there is no way to retrieve an attribute with **find()** ? Its only possible with the get* methods ? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As you said `"<xmlattr>.myattr"` is a _path_ only used with `get` and `get_optional`. I was then wondering if find() had some special writing to do the same. Thanks.